# How to keep long int during PHP string conversion?

Tags: php

The following PHP code:

```
$someID = 124234454288758;
$queryStr => "SELECT a FROM b WHERE some_id = {$someID}";
```

is converted to:

```
"SELECT a FROM b WHERE some_id = 1.2423445428876E+14"
```

How can I get the result string as:

```
"SELECT a FROM b WHERE some_id = 124234454288758"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GMP ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php ) or BCMath ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php ) when dealing with very large numbers.

Comment: does it mean the precision is already lost during the `$someID = 124234454288758;` assignment?

Comment: @ohho Try `var_dump($someID)`, if you see float(...), then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
number_format($someID, 0, '.', '');
```

Reference: [problems with big integers](http://jetlogs.org/2008/02/05/php-problems-with-big-integers-and-scientific-notation/)

Answer (score 1):

Since your not doing any math with the number (since it's just a unique key), why not just store it as a string.

```
$someID = "124234454288758";
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that SQL query creation like that is often open to SQL injection. You should probably consider using PDO and it's [`prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) functionality.

Comment: the number can be a result of another computation.

Comment: @ohho Something "smells", could you provide a little more context for the problem?

Comment: got it ;-) I have to make sure $someID not lossing precision first. Thanks!