# Big number base conversion and maximum limit

Tags: php, types, integer

I have this problem:

```
        // 7788778877887786660462040644602088666448 (10) = 9mwjmtyko1mpect1brz2exoncc (36)

    $a = 7788778877887786660462040644602088666450 - 2;
    echo $a."<br>"; // prints 7.7887788778878E+39
    $b = "9mwjmtyko1mpect1brz2exoncc";
    echo base_convert($b, 36, 10)."<br>"; //prints 7788778877887786660462040644602088666448
```

I know why `$a` was printed to `7.7887788778878E+39`, it's because the value of `$a` is over the integer limit.
But, why it is not being `7.7887788778878E+39` when I convert `9mwjmtyko1mpect1brz2exoncc` to decimal? It just prints the exact value (`7788778877887786660462040644602088666448`)
How can I print `$a` to the exact value (ignoring error)?
Is `7788778877887786660462040644602088666448` another data type that is bigger than long/unsigned-long?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some of the answers on this page:
[How to keep long int during PHP string conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253593/how-to-keep-long-int-during-php-string-conversion) 
I don't think you can do that because the large values are being stored as a float.

Suggestions are to use a library like [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php), but I think that those are not enabled in PHP by default.

Comment: I think you don't get what I meant. I want : If I echo `$a`, the printed string/number is `7788778877887786660462040644602088666448`.

Comment: So the output is same as `echo base_convert($b, 36, 10)`